# jQuery.validate.unobtrusive cannot work with MSDN email address RegEx

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

MSDN has [an example of validating email address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx) and below is the RegEx it used. It is the best RegEx I've seen bcz unlike all others, it recognizes xx@[IP Address] as a valid email address. My issue is that I can't make it work in MVC3 form validation. The jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.js throws an error saying "invalid group". Anybody experienced this before?

```
RegEx:

^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17}))$

MVC 3 Model:

[RegularExpression(@"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17}))$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorInvalidEmail", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(OptInOutResource))]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "lblUserName", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex was missing equals signs after the question mark in `(?(` (two occurrences)

Try this:

```
^(?=("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?=(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17}))$
```

They were meant to be look aheads `(?=<regex>)`